# Puppet - disable a user

Tags: linux, puppet, puppetmaster, sysadmin

I'm taking over an old puppet master, and I need to *disable* a user. I'm aware of "present", "absent", and "role", and they seem to be the only ones available.

I've been searching and honestly can't find anything.

If it helps, this user is only on debian systems.

Is there a way to accomplish this, without removing the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "disabling" a user?

If it's setting the login shell to /bin/false and the password to !, then do just that.

Comment: Huh, I probably just shouldn't have searched for puppet, then. You learn something new every day. Thanks for the answer!